# How to remove background of action menu item?

Tags: android

I have got the following action menu:

[image]

As you can see all of these action menu items are having a
background. i guess it is the same background like the parent.

How can i remove this background?

My style.xml is the following:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/custom_background_listview_item</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">beginning</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_background_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.PopupMenu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

My Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:focusable="false"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.PopupMenu"
app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: i added the styles.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is the problem

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_background_blue</item>
</style>
```

Since the above is applied not as style but as a theme (presumably via `popupTheme` attribute on your `Toolbar` element), all the widgets inside the toolbar inherit these settings. What you want is `android:popupBackground` instead of `android:background`.

Edit: OP stated the above is not sufficient. For styling toolbar's popup menu (not the toolbar itself) use the `app:popupTheme` attribute. The theme is going to be similar to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.PopupMenu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/custom_background_blue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I did not set a popupTheme attribute on my toolbar element (i post the toolbar code in my post) and no... unfortunately setting android:popupBackground = @null does not help to solve the problem

Comment: I really thank you for your answer but it again isnt working. i added 'app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.PopupMenu' my toolbar and set the 'android:popupBackground' to be red to test if it works. unfortunately i get the same result as you can see on the picture in the OP

Comment: the problem is that the textviews inside the overflow menu are always inheriting the background of their parent. if i set android:background inside the PopupMenu Style it is also set to the containing textviews. i dont want them to inerhit it. popupBackground simply has no effect because of that.

Comment: I really dont know how to fix that and hours of searching the web didnt help. nothing is working with my toolbar as descriped... my min api level is 21. could that be a problem?

Comment: Remove the `android:background` from theme declaration. Theme is applied to everything in a container so everything in your toolbar (including the toolbar) will have that custom background which you don't want to. Specify the toolbar background directly on the element or via `style` (not `app:theme`).

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the action background color explicitly in your style.xml same as the primary color.

```
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>
```

Try removing this from your XML or changing it to a color that seems appropriate for your UI and it should work. If you don't choose to manually specify a color for the android:actionModeBackground, it will simple derive it's default value from the parent theme (in your case, Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar).

Comment: No this does not change anything. the 'actionModeBackground' never took effect because i set my toolbar style to 'AppTheme.Toolbar' which i posted above. Also the dividers i defined there arent showing up.

Comment: Why not simple work with a theme that directly supports an Action Bar (Light or Dark, whichever you want) and then just specify colors for interface elements you care about?

Comment: Isnt that what im doing? My Designer cares about the title bar and the popup menu. Is it so hard to simply change the background of those overflow menu items?